# Approximation to the CDF of chi-squared random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, chi-squared

I am trying to simulate the approximation of the CDF of a chi-squared random variable, using the method proposed By [Luisa Canal2006](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luisa-Canal/publication/4899645_A_normal_approximation_for_the_chi-square_distribution/links/5afae217aca272e7302a7b70/A-normal-approximation-for-the-chi-square-distribution.pdf).

In [Luisa Canal2006](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luisa-Canal/publication/4899645_A_normal_approximation_for_the_chi-square_distribution/links/5afae217aca272e7302a7b70/A-normal-approximation-for-the-chi-square-distribution.pdf), the CDF of the $\chi_n^2$, denoted as $F_n(x,n)$, is approximated as $\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$.
And $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ is calculated as

$$
\mu=\frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{9 n}-\frac{7}{648 n^2}+\frac{25}{2187 n^3}\\
\sigma^2=\frac{1}{18 n}+\frac{1}{162 n^2}-\frac{37}{11664 n^3}
$$

It seems easy to simulate the numerical results.

However, I did not figure out the mistake of my Matlab code.
Here is my code:

---

[image]

---

And it shows that
[image]

The result in [Luisa Canal2006](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luisa-Canal/publication/4899645_A_normal_approximation_for_the_chi-square_distribution/links/5afae217aca272e7302a7b70/A-normal-approximation-for-the-chi-square-distribution.pdf) told that when $n=2$, the MAE (maximum absolute error) is just $1.8\times 10^{-3}$.
Obviously, my result is not consistent with that in [Luisa Canal2006](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luisa-Canal/publication/4899645_A_normal_approximation_for_the_chi-square_distribution/links/5afae217aca272e7302a7b70/A-normal-approximation-for-the-chi-square-distribution.pdf).

So, can anyone give me suggestions about this mis-consistence?

Thanks!